# Animate a character with walk cycle on a path

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, path

I have a animal character which is having a walk cycle and going on a path. I need the character to stop in some points and like look around and then continue on the path again. How do I do that?

Comment: you need to use the NLA editor, repeat a walk cycle strip, then put a strip above this track with the second action (stop and look around), then again the first strip. When he stops, create a keyframe on the curve.

Comment: I did that but then walking on the path totally stops and looking around action works.